# Better way to get the XML attribute value?

Tags: java, parsing, xml

I have an xml file from which I want to extract the value of attribute `custName` from the very first child. The code below works where I am using the dom parser. Is there a third-party library with which I can do the same with less code and more neatly?

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = (Document) db.parse(new File(
        tempDir));
    Node node = ((Document) document).getFirstChild();
    String custName= node.getAttributes()
        .getNamedItem("custName")
        .getNodeValue();
    assertEquals( "scott",custName);
```

Update:- Did the above approach use DOM4J (sorry but I am not sure)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the Java XPath API:

```
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(???); // ??? = InputStream or Reader
String custName = xpath.evaluate("//*[1]/@custName", inputSource);
```

There is a lot more information in this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

Comment: Hello @joe-f, the link to the article is broken, can you update it please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into using a different parser for this particular situation. [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)
contains good comparisons between java xml parsers. Maybe SAX or StAX is more suitable here?

Answer (score 1):

You can typecast the node to Element and then use getAttribute.
Eg:

```
String attributeValue = ((Element)yourNode).getAttribute("yourAttribute");
```